# Midway Neutral disconnects whole house supply

Tags: electrical, neutral

We have pretty good electrical wiring as an electronics hardware lecturer has recently changed certain wiring. Recently at one switch box in the mid-point of the house electrical wiring, when a neutral wire was disconnected, the whole house electrical supply got disconnected for a reason I don't understand.
And, whenever a small load is connected, the voltage drops, lights dim, and certain devices like the TV stop working!

Can anyone diagnose the problem? Some friend suggested a loose contact with the neutral. Could this be the culprit?

Comment: What country are you located?  Wiring methods do vary around the world.

Answer (score 3):

You have a broken neutral, and that is an emergency.  **Stop using anything right now** that is downstream of that neutral break and having voltage problems!!!

Those appliances meant for 120V could see 240V, and appliances made for 230V could see 400V.  This could fry them and start a fire.

Seriously.  Now!

Then go back and thoroughly go through all your wiring, especially anything that guy touched, and find that neutral problem and fix it.

Comment: This is probably India and they presumably have the UK system of single leg 230 V hot with neutral and ground.  If this is so, @Harper, how would that change your answer?

Comment: @JimStewart I would exchange "120 could see 240" and "230 could see 400", since the latter would be more likely applicable to him.

Comment: I thought that since there is only a single voltage provided in India (230 V)  that the effect of a loose or broken neutral would be low or zero current through devices. The most serious effect seems to me that there would be severe heating at the points of loose or partially broken neutrals which could start a fire.

Comment: If it's like the UK, it's 400v 3-phase wye, with any house getting 1-2 legs of it depending on their need.

Comment: The standard residential power in the UK is a single phase, single voltage of about 230 V at 50 hz. One hot, one neutral, one ground. Everything in the house from electric range and a/c compressor to receptacles to electric lights is powered at the same 230 V.

Comment: @JimStewart Here's how neighborhood distribution works US vs EU (note in the drawing most houses are getting 2 phases) http://electrical-engineering-portal.com/north-american-versus-european-distribution-systems So just install a big on-demand water heater, the power company will give you another phase rather than make you crazily upgrade a single phase (as must be done in the US.)  Then you can have lost neutral problems too!  Anyway OP said "midway neutral" which implies split phase or 2-phase.

Comment: I interpreted the term "midway neutral" as the OP referring to a neutral somewhere in the middle of the wiring in his house. Is this a term with a specific technical meaning? I do not think the OP would be aware of this.

Comment: The OP has not replied to questions so we are in the dark. I originally suggested that the OP was in India and this used the UK system. This is likely different from the EU in some respects. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity.